# Show that a group is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Let G be a group and m be a positive integer. Suppose that for all $\alpha, \beta \in G$, 
$$(\alpha \beta)^m = \alpha^m \beta^m,$$
$$(\alpha \beta)^{m+1} = \alpha^{m+1}\beta^{m+1},$$
and 
$$(\alpha \beta)^{m+2} = \alpha^{m+2}\beta^{m+2}.$$
Show that G is abelian.

Proof:

$(\alpha\beta)^{m+1}=\alpha\beta(\alpha\beta)^m = \alpha\beta\alpha^m\beta^m=\alpha^{m+1}\beta^{m+1}$. Multiply on the left by $\alpha^{-1}$ and on the right by $\beta^{-m}$, we get $\beta\alpha^m = \alpha^m\beta.$

On the other hand, $(\alpha\beta)^{m+1}=(\alpha\beta)^m\alpha\beta = \alpha^m\beta^m\alpha\beta = \alpha^{m+1}\beta^{m+1}$. Multiply on the left by $\alpha^{-m}$ and on the right by $\beta^{-1}$, we get, $\beta^m\alpha = \alpha\beta^m$.

$\alpha^{m+2}\beta^{m+2} =(\alpha\beta)^{m+2}=\alpha\beta(\alpha\beta)^m\alpha\beta = \alpha\beta\alpha^m\beta^m\alpha\beta=\alpha\alpha^m\beta\alpha\beta^m\beta =\alpha^{m+1}\beta\alpha\beta^{m+1}$. Multiply on the left by $\alpha^{-(m+1)}$ and on the right by $\beta^{-(m+1)}$. we get $\alpha\beta = \beta\alpha$.

Hence, for all $\alpha, \beta \in G$, $\alpha\beta = \beta\alpha$ and G is abelian.

Comment: This does not appear to be a question.

Comment: It's tagged as "proof verification" so perhaps user2675516 wants someone to check his/her work.

Answer (score 2):

$\checkmark$ I think this proof is correct in every detail. You could make it a little more readable by numbering the conditions at the top and stating clearly which you are using at each stage.